# Chrome: Caution: request is not finished yet

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot, google-chrome, networking

My tech stack includes react on UI and spring boot on server.

All the other api requests made to server work just fine but one request that has response of an array with a million records has this issue.

The response size is about 15mb and the request shows 200 as status code.
But the timing tab of the request shows this flag - Caution: request is not finished yet.

As long as this flag stays, the application becomes unresponsive.

On doing my research on this issue, I found that this means that chrome is expecting some more data as response.

Is there something to be mentioned in the response header to resolve this issue?

As the application becomes unresponsive,  how can this be terminated by a button click? I added axios cancel token but that cancels the request only if its pending and not when 200 comes as status.